# C# Auto increment primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server, auto-increment

I have already set the `IDENTITY` in the database to yes and whenever i run the application, the key doesnt auto increment giving an error about does not allow null values

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string fname = textBox1.Text;
            string lname = textBox2.Text;
            //int idnum = Convert.To(textBox3.Text);
            int mobnum = Convert.ToInt32(maskedTextBox1.Text);
            string email = textBox4.Text;

            int EdInst = comboBox1.SelectedIndex+1;
            string EdLev = comboBox3.SelectedText;
            string EdName = comboBox2.SelectedText;
            Boolean Valid = true;
            Valid = Validation(Valid);

            if (Valid == true)
            {
                IS2Team1_TriplexDBDataSet.ApplicantRow NewApplicantRow = iS2Team1_TriplexDBDataSet1.Applicant.NewApplicantRow();

                IS2Team1_TriplexDBDataSet.ApplicationRow NewApplicationRow = iS2Team1_TriplexDBDataSet1.Application.NewApplicationRow();

                //NewApplicantRow.Applicant_ID = ??;  // What do i do here for the ID to auto increment?
                NewApplicantRow.First_Name = fname;
                NewApplicantRow.Last_Name = lname;
                //NewApplicantRow.ID_Number =Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
                NewApplicantRow.Contact_Number = mobnum;
                NewApplicantRow.Email_Address = email;
                NewApplicantRow.University_ID = EdInst;

              //NewApplicationRow.Application_ID = ??; // What do i do here for the ID to auto increment?
                NewApplicationRow.Application_Status = "Recieved";
                NewApplicationRow.Application_Date = DateTime.Today;



                iS2Team1_TriplexDBDataSet1.Applicant.Rows.Add(NewApplicantRow);
                iS2Team1_TriplexDBDataSet1.Application.Rows.Add(NewApplicationRow);

                MessageBox.Show("Application Submitted", "Application Submitted");

                this.applicantTableAdapter.Update(this.iS2Team1_TriplexDBDataSet1);


                //Hide();
                //Form4 frmUpdate = new Form4();
                //frmUpdate.Show();

            }
                else if (Valid == false)
            {
                    MessageBox.Show("Required Information Missing");
                    textBox1.Focus();
            }
```

Comment: What's does your database structure look like?

Comment: Look at your adapter `InsertCommand`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the following Value in your Table-Definition:

[image]

**Sample: Not For Entity-Framework**:

If you want to insert a new Row, simply ignore your Identity-Row and
get the auto-generated Identity with: [@@Identity](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174639.aspx)

Hope this help!

**Here is an UNTESTED example:**

```
public static void Test()
    {
        int cIdentity = 0;

        SqlConnection cConnection = new SqlConnection("...");
        cConnection.Open();

        SqlCommand cCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO TestTable (Name) VALUES ('Test'); "+
            "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS Ident", cConnection);

        IDataReader cReader = null;

        try
        {
            cReader = cCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            if (cReader.Read())
            {
                cIdentity = cReader.GetInt32(0);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            if (cReader != null)
            {
                cReader.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (cConnection != null)
            {
                cConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How exactly do i get the auto-generated Identity with @@Identity? Could you give me an example on how to do it? Thanks:)

Comment: Example is now in my post :)

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the view of you're auto increment? it should be set as +1 or identity (1,1)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, ID's should not be edited when updating but still depending on the scenario, nevertheless Auto increment applies only in Inserting new details not updating. unless you changed the ID itself when updating.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the EDMX in your project, click on the column and look at the properties (F4). Set the StoreGeneratedPattern to Identity.

Comment: The StoreGeneratedPattern is already set to Identity. I thought i wouldnt have to insert a value to that column but it keeps breaking with the error Applicant_ID cannot be null

Comment: @user2806570 the identity itself should be set in the database. try that.

Comment: I have set it in the database already. (Is Identity) - Yes ,Identity Increment - 1 , Identity Seed - 1

Comment: @user2806570 could you post the error message and the inner exception message?